# Good mathematical introduction to loop quantum gravity

Tags: resource-recommendations, mathematics, loop-quantum-gravity

All websites or papers I could find did only have a mathless introduction for laymen. Does anybody know where to find a precise and mathematical introduction to LQG, for example containing the "interpretation" or "meaning" of holonomy groups and one-loop amplitudes in the theory?

Comment: http://www.imperial.ac.uk/media/imperial-college/research-centres-and-groups/theoretical-physics/msc/dissertations/2012/Suvi-Leena-Lehtinen-Dissertation.pdf

; http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.4577

Comment: @Hasan  That is exactly the kind of I paper I searched for, thank you !